# Is there any audio/sound package in Flutter that is affected by silent mode? Both Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, audio, soundpool

I tried with **audioplayers** and **soundpool**, but both packages are affected only by the volume level and not by the silent mode.

I'm trying to play some sounds when I press specific buttons in my app (currently using audioplayers) and mute this sounds when the silent mode is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code can help you. We can use `AudioContext`. I just tried on iOS, and it worked.

```
final audioContext =  AudioContext(
  iOS: AudioContextIOS(
    category: AVAudioSessionCategory.ambient,
    options: [AVAudioSessionOptions.mixWithOthers],
  ),
)
AudioPlayer.global.setGlobalAudioContext(audioContext);
```

Reference: https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/issues/1202#issuecomment-1399279247